# Error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int, trying to do a register in a store function Laravel 6.0

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

***I try to do some register with a query selector that returns me one number i tried to put it in another variable to save it but it said that was a string so then i tried to convert it to an int but says the error above***

1. Here it is the `Store function()` ,its for school

```sql
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $miembro = new Miembro();
        $miembro->razon_social=$request->razon_social;
        $miembro->denominacion_comercial=$request->denominacion_comercial;
        $miembro->web=$request->web;
        $miembro->rif=$request->rif;
        $miembro->save();
        $contact=new Telefono();
        $contact->codigo_area=$request->codigo_area;
        $contact->numero=$request->numero;
        $array = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT MAX(id_miembro)
                            FROM miembro
                            "));

        $aux=intval  ($array[0])  ;
        $contact->fk_miembro=$aux;
        $contact->save();
        return back();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB::select() does not automatically return an Array.

**Try:**

```
$array = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT MAX(id_miembro)
                            FROM miembro
                            "));

$result = array_map(function ($value) {
    return (array)$value;
}, $array);

$aux=intval($result [0])  ;
```